# I try to remove permissions from a user within a specific category

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to implement a system for my bot, that creates a personal area for a user per command. It contains a text channel and a voice channel. I've finished the creation command, the deletion command, the invite command but I am stuck at a kick command.

What the code is expected to do:

- Checks if the user has created a personal area
- Checks if the user they want to kick is in the voice channel (needs to disconnect them)
- Remove permissions from the selected user
- send a confirm message

What happens:
It removes permissions from the user but that's it. Nothing more happens.

The code. I programmed it by myself and it's in a cog. I'm new to python.

```
   @room.command(name='kick')
   async def _kick(self, ctx, user: discord.User):

       overwrites = {
           ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
       }                        
           
       guild = ctx.author.guild
       existing_cat = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='{}\'s Area'.format(ctx.message.author))

       #check if user has an existing category
       if existing_cat is None:
           await ctx.send(':x: **Du musst zuerst eine private Area erstellen.**')

       #if a category is found it beginns
       else:
           #searches for all channels in the category
           for channels in existing_cat.channels:
               #uses to disconnect the user if they're connected
               kickchannel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='waiting for kick')            
               #used to check if user is in the voice channel
               talk = discord.utils.get(existing_cat.voice_channels)
               members = talk.members
               #remove permissions from user
               await channels.set_permissions(user, read_messages=False)
               #searches for the spessific user
               for member in members:

                   if member.id == user.id:
                       #checks if users alreay got kicket from the category (as the deletetion of the kickchannel doesn't work)
                       if kickchannel is None:
                           await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name='waiting for kick', overwrites=overwrites, category=existing_cat)
                       #if the channel already exists it skipps the process
                       else: 
                           pass
                       #does the stuff to finish the kick if user is connected
                       await user.move_to(kickchannel)
                       await channels.set_permissions(user, read_messages=False)
                       await self.bot.delete_channel(kickchannel)
                       await ctx.send(f'**{user} wurde aus deiner privaten Area gekickt.**')
                       #if the user is not connected
                   else:
                       await channels.set_permissions(user, read_messages=False)
                       await ctx.send(f'**{user} wurde aus deiner privaten Area gekickt.**')
```

I get this error: My problem is that even without the line it doesn't work:

```
Ignoring exception in command room kick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
   ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/runner/Julian-DC-Bot/cogs/privatareas.py", line 124, in _kick
   await self.bot.delete_channel(kickchannel)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
   await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1340, in invoke
   await ctx.invoked_subcommand.invoke(ctx)
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
   await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
   raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_channel'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No. Nothing. Tried to find out with print('Test') after every several lines and everything after if member.id == user.id: didn't appear in my console

Comment: Except for the await self.bot.delete_channel(kickchannel). That one doesn't work. But even without it nothing works...

Comment: Do you have an error handler that is passing whenever there is an error? If you have one, you should always comment out the error handlers so that you can have a visualization of the errors you get when running the new command.

Comment: I added the error, but the code doesn't depend on it so without it also doesn't work.